# Highcharts - item parliament chart tooltip label for each point

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to create a highchart item parliament chart in which users can hover over each point rather than the group of points and get point-specific information.

In this artificial example, for instance, hovering over a specfic point would give you the name of the parliamentarian:

[image: Example item chart]

Is that possible at all?

To achieve this, I think, the data input would need to be changed as all item chart examples provide aggregate data, such as:

```
       data: [
            ['The Left', 69, '#BE3075', 'DIE LINKE'],
            ['Social Democratic Party', 153, '#EB001F', 'SPD'],
            ['Alliance 90/The Greens', 67, '#64A12D', 'GRÜNE'],
            ['Free Democratic Party', 80, '#FFED00', 'FDP'],
            ['Christian Democratic Union', 200, '#000000', 'CDU'],
            ['Christian Social Union in Bavaria', 46, '#008AC5', 'CSU'],
            ['Alternative for Germany', 94, '#009EE0', 'AfD']
        ]
```

The example item chart can be viewed [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series-item/dynamic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each point could be shown as a series, in which case you get a dedicated tooltip for them and add a key with a custom label.
This can be done with using [tooltip.pointFormat](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormat).

Example of series with custom label inside tooltip:

```
{
  name: 'Representatives2',
  keys: ['name', 'y', 'color', 'label', 'custom'],
  data: [
    ['Social Democratic Party1', 10, '#EB001F', 'SPD1','CUSTOM LABEL1'],
    ['Social Democratic Party2', 10, '#EB001F', 'SPD2','CUSTOM LABEL2'],
    ['Social Democratic Party3', 10, '#EB001F', 'SPD3','CUSTOM LABEL3'],
    ['Social Democratic Party3', 10, '#EB001F', 'SPD4','CUSTOM LABEL4'],
  ],
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true,
    format: '{point.label}'
  },

  // Circular options
  center: ['50%', '88%'],
  size: '170%',
  startAngle: -100,
  endAngle: -95
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wLn02qcv/

Comment: This is a workaround more than a solution. I asked in the highcharts forum and they told me that this is not currently possible with item chart, unfortunately.